# XML parser selector skips mixed content in migration

Tags: 8, migrations, feeds

I am trying to migrate and map the source fields of an external rss/xml file into Drupal.

I have built a custom module:

In `config/install` folder I have my `yml` file `modules/custom/import_rss/config/install/migrate_plus.migration.xml_articles.yml`:

```
id: xml_articles
label: 'Import articles'
status: true
source:
  plugin: url
  data_fetcher_plugin: http
  urls: 'https://myrss.xml'
  data_parser_plugin: simple_xml
  item_selector: /rss/channel/item
  fields:
    -
      name: guid
      label: GUID
      selector: guid
    -
      name: title
      label: Title
      selector: title
    -
      name: pub_date
      label: 'Publication date'
      selector: pubDate
    -
      name: link
      label: 'Origin link'
      selector: link
    -
      name: summary
      label: Summary
      selector: description
  ids:
    guid:
      type: string
destination:
  plugin: 'entity:node'
process:
  title:
    plugin: get
    source: title
  field_remote_url: link
  body: summary
  created:
    plugin: format_date
    from_format: 'D, d M Y H:i:s O'
    to_format: 'U'
    source: pub_date
  status:
    plugin: default_value
    default_value: 1
  type:
    plugin: default_value
    default_value: my_article
```

After running `drush mim xml_articles` all the items are imported except the `body` field in Drupal nodes are empty?

If I look at the source xml file the `<description>` tag looks like this:

```
<description><div class="field field-name-body field-type-text-with-summary field-label-hidden text-content text-secondary"><div class="field-items"><div class="field-item even"><p>You might have noticed some changes on Drupalize.Me lately. We've just wrapped up a huge content archiving project and I'd like to share what we did and how this will help us move forward with a library of tutorials for Drupal learners that we're committed to keeping up-to-date.</p>
</div></div></div></description>
```

In the XML source the `<description>` has 3 `<div>` tags `<description><div><div><div>Text</div></div></div></description>`

I tried as selector `description/*`, but that's not working either.

How do I get this working?

Comment: description/div/div/div?

Comment: @Kevin thanks I got it working by `description/div/div/div/*`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By adding `description/div/div/div/*` to the selector.